# Is the atmosphere of neutron star solid, liquid or gaseous state?

Tags: neutron-star, density, matter, stellar-atmospheres

Neutron star has a thin layer of atmosphere consist mostly of hydrogen and helium and is about less than a metre thick on average, but what wasn't stated in many articles I read is the state of matter of the atmosphere.

Comment: The word "atmosphere" implies that it's gaseous, or at least a gas-like plasma. That estimate of a metre thick seems way too large to me, I think a few millimetres down to a few microns is more realistic.

Comment: Here's a previous question about neutron star atmospheres, with a great answer. https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/14988/16685

Comment: Sliding off-topic,   "Dragon's Egg" by Robert Forward.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft but definitely on-topic in SciFi https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragons-egg

Comment: Hi @user6760 then I guess we'd better not take the quote in your profile literally! ;-) Is there anything here that's not answered in the proposed duplicate, or needs further clarification?

Comment: @uhoh: yes that's the answer I'm looking for.